# Is Form.IsDisposed Function return value when child form is closed?

Tags: c#

I made a small loading form to wait when main window sleeping.
So i use this code in my main form code.

```
Loading load = new Loading(); // Constructor of Loading Form
load.Show();
```

and i want to use .IsDisposed Function like this.

```
while(!load.IsDisposed)
{
    ...
}
```

can i?

Comment: if you do this in a new thread and sleep for 1ms between calls it should work

Comment: Really, a new thread in a WinForms app that talks to a Form. That won't work. Please describe what you want to do. What do you mean by _"a small loading form to wait when main window sleeping"_ (windows don't really _sleep_). Would making your _loading form_ modal suit your needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a child Form opened with [Form.Show Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.show?view=netframework-4.8) and would like to execute some code after it closes, you can subscribe to the form's `FormClosed` event. Try the following

```
//create new instance
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();

//subscribe to event(s)
frm2.FormClosed += Frm2_FormClosed;

//show Form
frm2.Show();

private void Frm2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    //ToDo: add desired code
}
```